# How to prevent Notepad++ changing font style for Autohotkey Comment

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey, syntax-highlighting

How to prevent Syntax Highlighting / Changing of font color if comments denoter semicolon does not have preceeding whitespace or has preceeding backquote for `Autohotkey` script in `Notepad++`.

Detail:

I code `AutoHotKey` script in `Notepad++`.

In this script semicolon denotes the start of the comment.

I use Autohotkey theme for Notepad++ mentioned [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=50) which tells which words or characters should have specified highlighting or font styles.

So `Notepad++` has semicolon as 'open comment style' in Language->Define your language...->Comment & Number->Comment line style->Open which tells to `Notepad++` to change  font color to green wherever semicolon starts.

[image]

So `Notepad++` highlights the characters start from semicolon otherwise enclosed by double quotes.

[image]

How to modify stylers.xml for `Notepad++` not to highlight if semicolon does not have preceeding whitespace or has preceeding backquote like below?

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer, but I'd recommend just writing code in an editor (IDE) that's meant for AHK. For example [SciTE4AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=62) or [AHK Studio](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=300). SciTE is a lighter editor that still has more or less everything you'd want. AHK Studio is a lot more feature rich, but also more complex of course.

Comment: The question states *"enclosed by double quotes"* but each pictures only shows one double quote. Showing pictures may help explain the problem but include the relevant text as text people can understand the problem and copy the text to see the problem and try solutions.